# Is it possible to edit the Tumblr default archive page?

Tags: tumblr

The default Tumblr archive page does not adhere to any of the CSS styles that have been set for the rest of the site. Here is the default tumblr archive page:

[image]

Is it possible to override or change the CSS & HTML of this particular page?

Comment: Only in your browser, not in others.

Comment: Yeah, I think maybe using the Tumblr API to create an archive would work?

Comment: I've tried that. It's a lot of work and requires a lot of API calls, and if someone is posting 100 posts per day, it's virtually pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this may be possible to to 'add a page' at the bottom of your blog's 'edit theme' menu and give it a custom layout. The page url must be '/archive' and from there you are able to write alternative code...

However once saved, hovering over the '/archive' page in the Menu will tell you 'This page overrides a built-in url' and so your code will not be used.

In answer to your question, no. No it is not possible.